# Derivative of Bezier Rectangle

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, bezier-curve

From this page [Derivatives of a Bézier Curve](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-der.html), I can see that the derivative of a degree $N$ Bezier curve is just a Bezier curve of degree $N-1$ and it explains how to calculate the control points by each control point just being $P_{i+1} - P_i$.

Is it also true that the derivative of a Bezier rectangle of degree $(M,N)$ is also just a Bezier rectangle of degree $(M-1,N-1)$?  If so, how would you calculate the control points for the rectangle?

By Bezier rectangle, I mean a tensor product Bezier surface, like the kind described here [Wikipediate: Bezier Surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface).

I've been trying to work it out on paper but no luck so far.  I've been able to make progress on coming up with a derivative, but it has quite a few terms even for a biquadratic patch, and i'd like to do this with higher degrees.

My end goal is that I'm trying to calculate the gradient of a univariate Bezier rectangle that has scalar control points.  Specifically, the rectangle takes $X$ and $Z$ values from 0 to 1 and outputs a $Y$ value for the given $(X,Z)$.  I want to find the gradient so that I can use it to calculate surface normals, as well as get a distance estimation for sphere tracing (ray marching).

Thanks for any help you guys can provide!

Comment: By a Bezier rectangle, do you mean a rectangle with rounded corners where the curves that make up the corners are Bezier curves? If so, [this](http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/bezier-paths-rounded-corners-rectangles.html) may be of help.

Comment: No sorry, i mean a tensor product Bezier surface.  Question updated, thanks for the excellent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true (almost). If the surface parameters are $u$ and $v$, the partial derivative wrt $u$ is a Bezier patch of degree $(M, N-1)$ and the partial derivative wrt $v$ is a Bezier patch of degree $(M-1, N)$.

If you are using the deCasteljau algorithm to calculate points on your patch, then the partial derivatives will be natural by-products.

Often the best way to handle a surface computation is to reduce it to a curve computation. So, suppose you want to calculate the partial derivative wrt $u$ at parameter values $(\bar u, \bar v)$ on the Bezier patch $(u,v) \mapsto \mathbf{S}(u,v)$. The curve $\mathbf{C}(u) = \mathbf{S}(u,\bar v)$ is a Bezier curve, whose control points are easy to obtain. The desired partial derivative is just the derivative of the Bezier curve $\mathbf{C}$ at the parameter value $u = \bar u$.

Comment: [These lecture notes](http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/zhx/GM/005/00-bcs2.pdf) explain on slide 49 how to extract a Bezier curve from a Bezier surface.